# How Do I Write "At [descriptor], ..." in Chinese?

Tags: grammar

In English, I can write "At *x* pages, *y*." where *x* pages refers to a document consisting of *x* number of pages and *y* is a description of the document. Example: At two pages, the proposed bill is short.

The Chinese equivalent of "at" is "在", however it applies to locations. "Pages" isn't a location in this case, so what would I write to convey "at" here? Or can I use "at" as I do in English?

My best guesses (using the preceding example) are "在兩頁，法案很簡短" and "包括兩頁，法案很簡短", but it's not clear to me whether either is correct.

Comment: 以长度（为）x页，该法案很简短

Comment: according to jukuu  and google translate 长度 is possible for length of a document, but 页数 seems to be another possibility

Comment: regarding use of 就。。。而论，就。。。来说（说来，看）see comment ＃２ of https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/25506/cant-discern-how-a-set-of-clauses-function -＞ 就x为页数而论，法案很簡短 see answers

Comment: I think you'd switch the logic for Chinese, basically you'd say "for a x it's very y."

Answer (score 2):

The Chinese way to say "At x pages, y."

> 1a. "**x pages  就 y 而言**"
>
> Example: 一百頁就小說而言真是很短" (one hundred pages for a novel is really short)
>
> 2a. "**就 y 而言, x pages**"
>
> Example: 就小說而言, 一百頁真是很短" (for a novel, one hundred pages is really short)

or

> 1b. "**x pages 以**/ **對 y 來說**, "
>
> 2b. "**以**/ **對 y 來說, x pages**"

1a, 1b are more literary

2a, 2b are more colloquial

Answer (score 1):

Chinese do not have equivalent expression.
Some similar ones:

**对于**法案来说, 两页不算长.

**针对**法案而言, 2页很短.

只有两页的方案, 算短的.

两页的方案算短的.